# Repercussions for Closing a Case

Tags: case, activities, solutions

We have been on Salesforce for about eight years.  We do not close cases.  There are several reasons for this, but the main one seems to be based on rumor.  There's some tradition here that when cases are closed, Salesforce does some things behind our backs.

The sort of thing that we have been concerned about are anything that affects:

1. that case showing up (differently or not at all) in reports or exports
2. that case's activities showing up (differently or not at all) in reports or exports
3. that case's activities showing up (differently or not at all) in reports or exports five years later
4. that case or its activities not being easily visible to users when looking at the case or the contacts on those activities.
5. that case's assigned solutions or other related records.

I tried searching the web for this, but cannot find evidence of any of this.  What, if any, are the repercussions for closing a case?  Did there used to be different repercussions?

Comment: Your system could be set up so behaviors like these happen...kinda depends on the reports and what sort of trigger architecture you have in place.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I understand we _can_ do whatever we'd like.  I want to know what the platform does automatically.

Comment: Tasks can be archived and not appear in reports once they have been completed for over a year but this happens regardless of Case closure. More info: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activities_archived.htm&language=en

Answer (score 3):

The only way the report or any of it's related items like activities are going to show up any different in your reporting is if the case status is a filter, or bucket, on a report. 
For the case to be easily visible to users, closing a case will not cause an issue, unless your users are using a custom list view that filters cases based on status.
Assigned solutions and related records are not effected by the status unless you have some type of triggered action, like a workflow or process builder firing on the case status changing.